# How to simulate real "visit" with fetch request inside service worker

Tags: javascript, request, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, fetch-api

I'm building an PWA with limited offline capability, I'm using this code to save page content to dynamic cache every time user visits a new url:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {

event.respondWith(
  fetch(event.request)
    .then(function(res) {
      return caches.open('cache')
            .then(function(cache) {
              cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
              return res;
            })
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log( err );
      return caches.match(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

This works great, after a page is loaded all of it assets are cached and can be seen in offline mode.

But, I would also like to add the option to automatically cache some of the more important urls when the user comes back online.

I do that by putting the list of urls in the array, loop through it and send a fetch request to each url, so those pages can be cached without user visiting/revisiting the page.

Problem is that when I do that some of the assets on some pages are not cached, for example google map on one page, is there a way to simulate real visit to a page, that gets all of the assets from an url with fetch request?

Fetch code:

```
 function fillDynamicCache(user_id = false) {
   let urls = [
    '/homepage',
    '/someotherpage',
    '/thirdpage',
    '/...',
   ];

   urls.map((url, id) => (
    fetch(url)
      .then(
        function(response) {
          if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
              response.status);
            return;
          }
          console.log( 'in fetch: ' + url );
        }
      )
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    })
  ));

  }


self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
// refresh cache when user comes back online
if (event.data == 'is_online') {
    fillDynamicCache();
} else if (event.data == 'is_updated') {
    self.skipWaiting();
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically if you have important assets you want to provide the users, even when they are offline, you should consider an **offline first** strategy, meaning you prefetch those resources while the service worker is installing.

This way the matching requests will be served from the cache, improving the performance because you skip the relative network calls entirely.

In case the target resources tend to update/change frequently on the server, then you can opt for a **stale while revalidate** strategy (after the data is provided from the cache, the SW will update its value with a newer one from the network, if available) or even **network first, fallback to cache**, the latter if you want to provide always the latest values and provide cache data only if the network connection times out or is unavailable.

[I wrote an article about service worker and caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f), in case you want to go deeper into the topic.